# Return multiple values through Jquery post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've returned 2 dates from a PHP script through `$.post()`. Then I'm trying to break up the results into two variables (the commented out portion under the console.log) , instead of appearing in one variable.

Below is the jquery code:

```
   $.post('api/displayDBSetTimes.php', function(data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item) {
     console.log(item.DB_ST);

     /* var db_st = item.DB_ST;
      var db_et = item.DB_ET;
      return db_st + " " + db_et;*/
      return item;

    });
    $('#oecd').html(htmlToInsert);
  });
```

The PHP is below.  I formatted the dates in the PHP script before sending out in JSON.  The commented out jquery code above worked before I formatted the dates in PHP:

```
 <?php 
 include_once("../include/sessions.php");
 $select = "SELECT start_time AS DB_ST, end_time AS DB_ET FROM countdown WHERE tid = 1;";
     $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $select);

if($query){
    $out = array();
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $out[] = date('D, m-d-Y H:i:s A', strtotime($row['DB_ST']));
        $out[] = date('D, m-d-Y H:i:s A', strtotime($row['DB_ET']));
    }

    // encode array as json and output it for the ajax script
    echo json_encode($out);
    }
   ?>
```

Every time I try to refer to the PHP variable in the jQuery `$post()` function (ie.  `item.DB_ST` in the console.log) it returns as `undefined`, but if I remove the PHP variable reference, the 2 dates come back as one big string. I don't want that. I don't know why it's coming back undefined if I reference one part of the array.

Could someone help me?  Would `ajax()` be better for something like this? The help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set associative arrays in your PHP file...

```
$out['DB_ST'] = date('D, m-d-Y H:i:s A', strtotime($row['DB_ST']));
$out['DB_ET'] = date('D, m-d-Y H:i:s A', strtotime($row['DB_ET']));
```

And in your $.post you have to indicate the response is going to be in JSON format...

```
$.post('api/displayDBSetTimes.php', function(data) {

    /* Here you can access directly to data.DB_ST and data.DB_ET */

},'json');
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it does!   Thank you so much!

Comment: Good to hear! Have a nice day and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use associative array in PHP, in order to achieve key-value pairs.

```
$out['DB_ST'] = date('D, m-d-Y H:i:s A', strtotime($row['DB_ST']));
$out['DB_ET'] = date('D, m-d-Y H:i:s A', strtotime($row['DB_ET']));
```

Comment: hnewbie, can you accept my answer also, as it was posted earlier actually? :) Thanks!

Comment: It looks like I can only accept one answer.  :(  Since A. Iglesias helped me out on both ends (PHP & Jquery), I feel that his answer was more complete.

Comment: No problem! Cheers.

Comment: Thank you though!